# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4 in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an AsyncTask to run database querying in the background.
I get this error when I run my applection.

```
05-27 16:35:13.638: I/Choreographer(3421): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 16:35:13.859: I/Choreographer(3421): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at com.example.iqraa.Buy$SearchBook.doInBackground(Buy.java:189)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at com.example.iqraa.Buy$SearchBook.doInBackground(Buy.java:1)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     ... 4 more
05-27 16:35:14.469: I/Choreographer(3421): Skipped 134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 16:35:15.369: I/Choreographer(3421): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 16:35:16.309: I/Choreographer(3421): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 16:35:22.089: I/Process(3421): Sending signal. PID: 3421 SIG: 9
```

Here is my AsyncTask@buy.java:

```
  public class Buy extends Activity {
    String ISBN="";
    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS = 0;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    String s;
    String index;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
```

Answer (score 1):

based on your logcat, I can sense the error occurs in catch block of doinbackground function.

You are using toast in that method, toast cannot be executed in background. that should be in main thread.

So actual error is at line 189, what ever is at 189 is null. So it is going to catch and throwing another error at toast.

Answer (score -1):

according to your logcat, you have an error on line 189

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 05-27 16:35:14.029: E/AndroidRuntime(3421): at com.example.iqraa.Buy$SearchBook.doInBackground(Buy.java:189) 05-27 16:35:14.029:
```

So something on that line is not initialized and your trying to access it.

Comment: thank you a lot for your quick answer and i appreciate it , it solve a part of the problem and there is no returned errors but without any displaying for data (no return data displayed)

Comment: there is a problem still exist which there is no returned data to displayed, i don't know the why ???

Comment: add return MyArrList; after your for loop

Comment: the program execution skip the for loop so no data returned , i alter the code as you mentioned above (return MyArrList) ,proplem still exist

Comment: what is it doing when no data is returned, and what should it be doing?

Comment: when there is a data it must be populated in the custom list,

Comment: change onPostExecute to: protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> unused) that mehtod as is may not get called

Comment: i follow exactly what you wrote;i trace the program execution by putting many    Log.d     , still the program execution skip entering the loop to populate the custom list ,

Comment: Can you past your json, also try putting a breakpoint at if(data != null) and check that.